# Defining the read-out value of a textbox for screen readers

Tags: accessibility, htmlcontrols

Working on accessibility, have a textbox containing a date (format depends on language selected). Screen readers read the date currently in the textbox letter-by-letter ("Twelve-slash-oh-five-slash-twenty-thirteen" for 12/05/2013).

1) How can I tell the reader program to read out "twelfth may twenty-thirteen"?

2) How can I tell the reader the format required by the textbox to be typed in? e.g. "day-slash-month-slash-year"

I'm new to this topic and not familiar with the concepts. Any ideas or hints, links to details or concepts are very much welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) you  can't. I wouldn't worry about it.

2) Screen readers need `<label>`s to be read correctly, you can do it like so

```
<label for="date">Birthday (DD/MM/YYYY)</label>
<input id="date" name="date" type="text"/>
```

If you want to hide the formatting, you can do:

```
 <label for="date">Birthday <span class="hidden">DD/MM/YYY</span></label>
```

where hidden is:

```
.hidden {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: -999px;
}
```

Comment: One more question: I don't want the DD/MM/YYYY text be visible. Will something like this work? <label>Birthday<span class="hidden">DD/MM/YYYY</class></label> - Ideally, it would NOT display but DO read out.

Comment: if you're hiding the date text, doesn't that defeat the purpose of worrying about screen readers? the date text informs the user how the date is to be inputted, hiding it (i think) defeats the purpose of worrying about.

Comment: I would argue that other elements on the screen may lead to knowing the format, but I agree with Albert that it hiding it shouldn't be done. The only hiding would be done would be dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Sighted users have a date picker to use and displaying the format. What if I just make is display:none? Will it be read out?

Comment: Adding a date picker adds a new set of issues for assistive technology and those who use the keyboard. See: http://webstandardssherpa.com/reviews/curing-the-jetblues scroll about halfway down to the getting stuck at the airport

Comment: Since it wasn't mentioned, I just type here my expreience so that others may benefit from it: "display: none" will make Chrome and Ffox to not read out the text. That's why Ryan defined hidden as left: -999px.